# UART level shifter: strange level

Tags: uart, level-shifting

This is my circuit

[image]

Scoping on the UART host side I have the following trace

[image]

[image]

But on the device side (3.3V) I have this trace

[image]
[image]

Not sure on what I am doing wrong there...

Using this NMOSFET: [BSD840N](https://4donline.ihs.com/images/VipMasterIC/IC/INFN/INFN-S-A0000088794/INFN-S-A0000088794-1.pdf?hkey=6D3A4C79FDBF58556ACFDE234799DDF0)

Comment: Please check the MOSFET is connected the right way around. You should be getting 0.94-1.1 volts on the device side.

Comment: I think you've mis-identified the pins of the MOSFET. Based on the fact that the swing you're getting on the device side is approximately a diode drop, I think you may have G tied to the host, S tied to +3.3V and D tied to the device. The swing you're seeing is purely capacitive coupling from G to D, limited by the body diode's forward drop.

Comment: Note that this type of level shifter is bi-directional, intended for low-speed connections such as I2C. There are better solutions for unidirectional connections, especially if you're running close to 1 Mbps, given that this one relies on passive pullups.

Comment: Which is the MCU output, 5V or 3.3V side? What is on the input side?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my MOSFET was defective.

I have measured the voltage at the gate  when I removed 3.3V and I have basically 5V.

Don't know how I managed to damage the MOSFET but I replaced it with a new one and now I have 0V on the gate when I disconnect 3.3V from it.

And now I have a signal at the source.

This is the trace from the new MOSFET

[image]

this is the trace from the first MOSFET probing at the exact same spot

[image]

Comment: I removed your question at the end since this is posted as an answer (and it does answer the question well). If you'd prefer to ask if the damaged gate explains it, I suggest you post this as an edit to your question or perhaps ask a new question.